# How can I prove that $X$ is $\sigma(X^2)$ measurable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

> I have given a random variable $X\sim U[-1,1]$ and want to prove if it is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable where $Y=X^2$

In order to understand the definition of $\sigma(Y)$-measurable a bit better I wanted to work with the definition. I somehow get a bit colfused with the definition. Because normally we write $f:(E,\epsilon)\rightarrow (E',\epsilon')$ is $\epsilon$-$\epsilon'$-measurable and do not only indicate one $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that $\sigma(Y)=\{Y^{-1}(A):A\in \mathfrak{B}([0,1])\}$ where $\mathfrak{B}$ denotes the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra.Now I would say that $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable if for all $B\in \sigma(Y)$ $$X^{-1}(B)\in \sigma(Y)$$ I would prove this as follows:

**Proof** Let $B\in \sigma(Y)$, i.e. $B=Y^{-1}(A)$ for some $A\in \mathfrak{B}([0,1])$. Then $X^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(Y^{-1}(A))=(Y\circ X)^{-1}(A)$

But now I do not see where to conclude.

Could maybe someone help me further?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ is not $\sigma (X^2)$-measurable... Having the information on $X^2$ don't allows to have information on $X$... Indeed, $X=f(X^2)$ for some function $f$, then $f$ is not well defined since you would have for example $$-1=f((-1)^2)=f(1)=f(1^2)=1.$$

However, it would have been the case if for exemple $X\sim \mathcal U[0,1]$ or $X\sim U[-1,0]$.

Comment: Could you maybe explain briefly what $\sigma(Y)$ measurable mean in general?

Comment: Because given $X:(E, \epsilon)\rightarrow (E,\epsilon ')$ I know that $\sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(A'):A'\in \epsilon '\}$

Comment: @Haveaniceday: $$\sigma (Y):=\{Y^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}=\{Z:\Omega \to \mathbb R\mid \exists f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\text{ measurable },Z=f(Y)\}.$$ Notice that in context of probability, $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ being measurable implicitly means "Borel measurable", i.e. that $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ for all $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Why do you take the Borel sigma algebra?

Comment: Because $X\sim \mathcal U[-1,1]$, i.e. $X$ is a real r.v. and the definition of a real r.v. it's that $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is measurable, which means that $X^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal F$ for all $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Ah no I mean in a general setting sorry. Because I think I do not get the general definition. So if I take $X$ as in the second comment then I know what $\sigma(X)$ is. But then for a further r.v. $Y$ when is this random variable $\sigma(X)$ measurable by definition and not by saying $Y=f(X)$.

Comment: I do not know from where to where my $Y$ should go and which domain has which sigma algebra

Comment: $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ is $\sigma (X)$ measurable $\iff \{Y\in B\}\in \sigma (X)$ for all $B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\iff \exists f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R\text{ measurable (in Borel sense) }$s.t. $Y=f(X)$. You can take one of the two as a definition and prove the other one...

Comment: but does $\{Y\in B\}\in \sigma(X)$ means that $Y^{-1}(B)\in \sigma(X)$

Comment: and using the second definition why can't I say that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is the searched function?

Comment: because $x=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ is not true for all $x\in [-1,1]$. Yes $\{Y\in B\}=Y^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Ah I See now perfect thanks a lot.